# How to load CICS parameters update after defining DFHSIT SPOOL=YES system intialization parameter?

Tags: jcl, cics

I updated the DFHSIT$$ in CICSTS54.CICS.SDFHSAMP where I changed SPOOL=NO to SPOOL=YES. How can I make CICS to load the updated table?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that you have updated your SIT table in DFHSIT$$ you will need to compile it, see https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cics-ts/5.4?topic=parameters-assembling-sit for details.

Once the compilation has been done you will need to restart your CICS region for it to pick up the changes.  I assume that you already have SIT=$$ specified within the SIT overrides in the CICS JCL, for example:

```
//SYSIN    DD *                                                       
SIT=$$
.
.
.
/*
```

Comment: Yes I have already specified SIT=$$ in the start up job stream, but it's still giving me error.  I will attach here my CICS JCL. if you have time, can you help me find what I did wrong? thanks. I really appreciate it. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eN-xSTM6DTnEplr-ToX4ynl_X-iXH5iB/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The JCL you have posted looks to be a COBOL compile job and not a CICS Job.

Comment: How about this one? https://drive.google.com/file/d/1X5VMEkN5w0of3uNkBWuSulgIF0bLnusl/view?usp=sharing . I have a feeling this is the start up JCL, but there's not in stream DD for EXEC PGM=DFHSIP. Also, the reason why i don't know this CICS start up JCL is because everytime I go to CICS region, I just go to file > new session > L CICS because I use the Vista TN3270.

Comment: Also please tell me if I'm not allowed to post that licensed source code, I'll delete it ASAP. I'm still training to be a mainframe developer and doesn't know much about rules.

Comment: So the SIT overrides in the DFHSTART proc are held within the member DFH$SIPT see about line 115.  You could if you choose to override SPOOL=YES within that member that is include or you could update the PARM on the CICS step adding, 'SPOOL=YES' after the USSHOME paramter.

Comment: Thanks Sir Adam. You've been very helpful. One last thing, so if I override SPOOL=YES within DFH$SIPT member and submit the DFHSTART proc, will this work?

Comment: Yep that should do the override, when CICS starts you should be able to see the SIT overrides in the job output.

Answer (score 0):

what you have posted is a translate,compile and link edit for a COBOL program. The DFHSIT table is an assembler table which needs to be assembled using the assembler.

However, what would be easier for you in this case would be to not assemble a new version of the default DFHSIT table. Instead, just add a SPOOL=YES to the SIT overrides when you start CICS.

The sit overrides are set in SYSIN on your CICS startup JCL
e.g.

//SYSIN    DD *
SPOOL=NO

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. Do you know where this CICS startup JCL is usually stored? I have checked the hlq.CICS.SDFH libraries but I can't find any that include EXEC PGM=DHSIP, the dd statement below this EXEC statement is where I should be able to add SPOOL=YES right?

Comment: not really - the startup JCL could be anywhere of your choosing on your system